# Second posting of: scp error: “Permission denied (publickey). lost connection”

Tags: unix, scp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [scp error: “Permission denied (publickey). lost connection”](https://superuser.com/questions/95171/scp-error-permission-denied-publickey-lost-connection)

This posting is a reposting of:

[scp error: "Permission denied (publickey). lost connection"](https://superuser.com/questions/95171/scp-error-permission-denied-publickey-lost-connection)

(At Stack Overflow, I had posted it without using an OpenID. After it was migrated to Super User, I didn't know how to post or answer to comments, if I could at all. I am doing this reposting with my OpenID.)

Regarding comments on the posting, after migration:

@sth: I don't know much about public keys. The creation times for the files id_rsa and id_rsa.pub are recent.

@Jim Lewis: Thank you for the advice about verbose options and not posting things online. Below is the output of scp with the -vvv option. Near the beginning is information about a bad RSA1 key file. How do I fix this?

```
    [wcyang@be2-wireless-pittnet-60-41 .ssh]$ scp -vvv diffcolor-dump.bz2 wcyang@dl.sv.gnu.org:/srv/download/diffcolor/
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host dl.sv.gnu.org, user wcyang, command scp -v -t /srv/download/diffcolor/
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.7l 28 Sep 2006
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to dl.sv.gnu.org [140.186.70.73] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/wcyang/.ssh/identity type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /Users/wcyang/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug1: identity file /Users/wcyang/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/wcyang/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour128,arcfour256,arcfour,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 135/256
debug2: bits set: 528/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /Users/wcyang/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /Users/wcyang/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
debug1: Host 'dl.sv.gnu.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/wcyang/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 526/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/wcyang/.ssh/identity (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/wcyang/.ssh/id_rsa (0x107fd0)
debug2: key: /Users/wcyang/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/wcyang/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /Users/wcyang/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/wcyang/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/wcyang/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/wcyang/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

Comment: IMO, the RSA1 warning can be safely ignored. RSA1 means a RSA key for SSH protocol version v1, which is very insecure and very obsolete. Also, the `Offering public key: /Users/wcyang/.ssh/id_rsa` line says that file contains a valid SSHv2 RSA key and that the server rejected it.

Comment: @grawity: Thank you for the information.